# mpirun with socwatch fails

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi, intel-socwatch

On trying to measure energy consumption on my system with an OpenMPI program.

For OpenMPI, we can run with

```
mpirun -n 4 ./hello
```

This program will print hello from 4 processes.

Now, If it is a C++ program, we can run SocWatch with it as

```
sudo socwatch -m -f sys -f wakelock -t 35 -p ./hello
```

With OpenMPI, I try

```
sudo socwatch -m -f sys -f wakelock -t 35 -p mpirun -n 4 ./hello
```

But the program is stropped because socwatch did not recognize to mpi-run.

How to run SoCWatch with MPI

Comment: Try replacing `mpirun` with `$(which mpirun) --allow-run-as-root`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason would be mpirun is in your `$PATH` as a user, but is no more in your `$PATH` when sudo is used. Try using the absolute path to mpirun instead. Note you will need to pass the `--allow-run-as-root` option to mpirun.